# Gallery image do not show on page load when using css transition

Tags: css, image, css-transitions, image-gallery, squarespace

I have made this page

http://safari-as.squarespace.com

On the main page it is a gallery made from a squarespace template. I wanted to add transition between the images on the gallery.

This was done by adding this to the css:

```
.slide {
-webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
   -moz-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
    -ms-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
     -o-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
        transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.420, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); /* ease-in-out */
    }
```

The problem is that after this change the big photo in gallery will not sho UNTIL you resize the browser window.

Do anyone know how to make sure that the big image will show on page load?

Answer (score 0):

Ive had the same problem with webkit browsers. The only solution ive found so far is removing cubic-bezier from -webkit-transition: and replacing it with

.slide { -webkit-transition: opacity ms ease-in-out;}